# Define Environment Variables referring to variable environment for a Container [kubernetes]

Tags: linux, maven, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

I have a K8s deployment for a spring boot application
I want to create a dump file `.hprof` with the name of the pod ($hostname)

My `JAVA_OPTIONS` parameters is a variable environment 
I want to refer to another variable inside the parent `JAVA_Options`

```
containers:
- env:
  - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
    value: prod,swagger
  - name: JAVA_OPTS
    value: ' -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/$HOSTNAME.hprof'
```

What I expected is to have a variable that contains the hostname :

```
$ echo $JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/myPodNameStaging.hprof
```

What I have as a result is: 
`$HOSTNAME.hprof` is set as a string.

I also tried many combinations `$(HOSTNAME)` `${HOSTNAME}`. Always I got the name of the variable and not the content value.

My question is: How to refer to the `$HOSTNAME`

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying this using nginx, however the variable substitution is working, perhaps you can try it:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: POD_HOSTNAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: prod,swagger
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/$(POD_HOSTNAME).hprof
```

And after that I can see the content of `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
root@nginx-deployment-5bc5fcdc8b-f4ldx:/# echo $JAVA_OPTS
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/10.32.17.138.hprof
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Important note - if env variable B is dependent on variable A, variable A NEEDS to be defined before it is used in B, exactly like you have described above.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You will need to define these some other way or otherwise handle the interpolation yourself. A common option is something like this:

```
command:
- sh
- -c
- |
  JAVA_OPTS="asdfasdf" java -whatever
```

But that does require fully overriding the command from the underlying container which is annoying. That said, you *can* do limited replacements in volume paths so probably handle it at that level instead for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

The hostname of pods in Kubernetes is always the same as the pod name and on Linux we have a env variable $HOSTNAME. So you can use it to achieve what you need:

Here is an example that may suit your needs:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox:1.24 
    env:
    - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
      value: prod,swagger    
    command: [ "sh", "-c"]
    args:
    - while true; do
        export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/$HOSTNAME.hprof";
        printenv JAVA_OPTS;
        printenv SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE;
        sleep 10;
      done;
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
```

If you run `kubectl get logs busybox` you can see this output:

```
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/busybox.hprof
prod,swagger
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/busybox.hprof
prod,swagger
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/busybox.hprof
prod,swagger
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/busybox.hprof
prod,swagger
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/busybox.hprof
prod,swagger
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/jvm-data/busybox.hprof
prod,swagger
```